# What free python hosting service/server exists that let you run python code every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, server

I am not sure this is the right place to ask, but I did not found any better stack- place.

I am looking for a free web service/hosting service where I can run a simple python script every 5 minutes (using crontab etc.). I especially require the following requirements:

- It has to be free (or really affordable)
- It has to be password protected
- It has to be able to run python 3x
- It must have internet access
- It has to be able to run a single script every 5 minutes.

The CPU/memory requirements are very low.

I did look into `pythonanywhere`, but this service let's you run a script only once a day. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Check out the free plan of various server-less services that support Python.

Comment: @Deadlock Maybe you can give some concrete examples?